# SQL Insert? insert data from one to another

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

Firstly please understand that SQL is not one of my strong areas at the moment and i am a little unsure why i cannot get the query to-do this, it seems possible.

we are running a mysql server v5.1

i have a filenotes table that i need to insert a single record into for a list of clients we have.

so i did this.

```
insert into filenote(clientid, notetype, datetime, notedetails)
    VALUES (clienttable.clientid, 'info','2011-09-29 09:00:00', 'example note')

select clienttable.clientid from clienttable 
    where clienttable.clientid in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

however i keep getting errors from SQL relating to the select statement, there is no indication in the error to what the problem is though, it just states.

> "you have an error in your SQL syntax near select clienttable.clientid
>   from clienttable where clienttable.clientid in ("

whilst i know there is a problem there i cannot see what that problem would be. please be aware that the field names do not match in the tables.

this is the example i followed.

```
INSERT INTO Store_Information (store_name, Sales, Date)
SELECT store_name, Sales, Date
FROM Sales_Information
WHERE Year(Date) = 1998
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute both sentences in the same SQL script? If so, you need a semicolon at the end of each one (or launch them separately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up two different styles of `INSERT`.

To use the same method as your example, you'd need to do:

```
INSERT INTO filenote(clientid, notetype, datetime, notedetails)
SELECT clientid, 'info','2011-09-29 09:00:00', 'example note'
FROM clienttable
WHERE clienttable.clientid in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

or use `BETWEEN`:

```
INSERT INTO filenote(clientid, notetype, datetime, notedetails)
SELECT clientid, 'info','2011-09-29 09:00:00', 'example note'
FROM clienttable
WHERE clienttable.clientid BETWEEN 1 AND 9
```

Comment: the first part of this example worked perfectly, as my realworld list of client id's does not run in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into filenote(clientid, notetype, datetime, notedetails)
select clienttable.clientid, 'info','2011-09-29 09:00:00', 'example note' from clienttable 
where clienttable.clientid between 1 and 9
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however i cannot use the between statement as in the real sql example the clientid numbers are not in sequence, there is a list of nearly 1000 id's none of them follow each other.

Comment: @Kristiaan - the order of them doesn't matter. `between` is just a range operator and will do the same thing.

Comment: are you saying that for example my list starts at 60000 and ends at 100000 and there is no 70000 client ids in the list that BETWEEN wont update the 70000 client id records?, surely between just means go from number a to number b and all numbers between?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO filenote(clientid, notetype, datetime, notedetails)
SELECT clienttable.clientid, 'info','2011-09-29 09:00:00', 'example note'
FROM clienttable
WHERE clienttable.clientid in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```