# MySQL INSERT working properly as documented

Tags: php, mysql

What im trying to do is I have an Table called m_select which has four fields --> id, id_m, hello, bye .. two of those fields i want to get from variables in the script which are id and id_m and two of those from a different table called test1 using SELECT ... IS that possible.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO m_select [(id, id_m, hello, bye)] VALUES [('$U','$$t_id')] SELECT hello,bye FROM test1 [WHERE id='$test_id']");
```

Comment: You are trying to insert a row and then retrieve the newly inserted row in one operation? You cannot via `mysql_query()`.  Or are you trying to do an `INSERT INTO...SELECT FROM...` statement?  Either way, there are definitely no square brackets `[]` in SQL...

Comment: You are inserting into m_select table and selecting from test1. There is no relation between the queries, why do you want to use it in a single statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Insert? insert data from one to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596116/sql-insert-insert-data-from-one-to-another)

Comment: Please correct the question as well what you want not clearly describe in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO
    m_select
    (id, id_m, hello, bye)
   SELECT
     '$U' AS id,
     '$$t_id' AS id_m,
     hello,
     bye
   FROM test1 WHERE id='$test_id'
");
```

I'm not sure whether the double-dollar sign on `$$t_id` (rather than `$t_id`) is intentional or not, but I thought I'd at least make you aware of it.

Comment: thanks my friend.  What im trying to do is I have an Table called m_select which has four fields --> id, id_m, hello, bye .. two of those fields i want to get from variables in the script which are id and id_m and two of those from a different table called test1 using SELECT ... IS that possible. this solution now working

Comment: i'm working on putting an example together now. one moment...

Comment: hmm, that query should work.. what's the error you're getting?

Comment: its working brother .. thanks ... misspelled something

Answer (score 1):

Your statement has several problems.  One is the square brackets.  More importantly, you are specifying two columns with values but have four columns in the `insert` statement.  This seems to be what you want:

```
INSERT INTO m_select (id, id_m, hello, bye)
   VALUES ('$U','$$t_id')
```

You can add additional values:

```
INSERT INTO m_select (id, id_m, hello, bye)
   VALUES ('$U','$$t_id', 'hello', 'bye')
```

Or remove them from the column list:

```
INSERT INTO m_select (id, id_m)
   VALUES ('$U','$$t_id')
```

Comment: BUt i want to get the hello, bye from the test1 values

Comment: @lollol . . . Then don't include them in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Am... remove square brackets...
And place SELECT to separate query.

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO m_select (id, id_m, hello, bye) VALUES ('$U','$t_id') SELECT hello,bye FROM test1 WHERE id='$t_id'");

Answer (score 0):

**First a fall insert the data into the table using PHP:**

```
function insertFunction(){
    $query = "INSERT INTO test1(id, id_m, hello, bye) VALUES('$id','$id_m','$hallo','$bye')";
    try {
       $runQuery = mysql_query($query);
       if (!$runQuery) throw new Exception("mysql Error");
    } catch(Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**After that fetch the results:**

```
function selectFunction(){

        $resultantQuery = "SELECT id,id_m,hello,bye FROM test1";
        try {
               $runQuery = mysql_query($resultantQuery);
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($runQuery);
              echo "id:" .$result['id'];
              echo "id_m:" .$result['id_m'];
              echo "hello:" .$result['hello'];
              echo "bye:" .$result['bye'];

               if (!$runQuery) throw new Exception("mysql Error");
            } catch(Exception $e) {
               echo $e->getMessage();
            }

}
```

Comment: Not what im looking for . . What im trying to do is I have an Table called m_select which has four fields --> id, id_m, hello, bye .. two of those fields i want to get from variables in the script which are id and id_m and two of those from a different table called test1 using SELECT ... IS that possible.