# String not inserting into DB php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert something into a field into the databse but its only working with integers. I switched the field to `varchar` and `text` but still not working.Any help would be appreciated.

I want the variable `$r1="value"` to go into the `DB`

```
 case 'X':
         $r1 = "X";
         mysql_query("UPDATE test SET draw = draw + 1 WHERE id = '$test_id'");
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO match_select (user_id, match_id, liga, home, away, result) SELECT '$username' AS user_id, '$test_id' AS match_id, '$liga' AS liga, home, away, $r1 AS result FROM test WHERE id='$test_id'");

 break;
```

Comment: your information is not sufficient to answer your query.

Comment: You just made a little mistake by copy-and-pasting over from an answer you've got: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17181354/367456 - Instead of asking better take care that you properly adopt an example code.

Comment: Obviously you didn't. With copy and pasting you would not have done that error. However, what you did was using (copy and pasting in the more broad sense) that answer without understanding the code fully. Before using the code, you need to read it and you need to understand everything it does. And why rude? I just point to the problem in a comment, that's what comments are for on this website.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As soon as it's a string - it should be enclosed in quotes

```
... home, away, '$r1' AS result ...
```

Comment: Right lol...Thanks man .. Forgot all about it . LOL. Can't accept the answer for another 6 min.

Comment: @zerkms: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17181354/367456

Comment: this detail was already part of the original answer the user just has gotten some hours ago on this website on the related question.

Comment: @hakre: I'm missing the point actually :-S I've answered to this particular question

Comment: ***You have duplicated the existing answer*** - a link would have been enough, a little comment pointing to the problem. Just saying, you might not have been aware about the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

As You are using Varchar as datatype in mysql for your column, You must have to use the character literals for values. like: '$r1'